# Using Unison to sync only folders named `src`

Tags: sync, unison

I have a laptop which is connected to a cloud workstation. All my compilation happens on the cloud workstation, but I modify files on my laptop. I want to sync files between the two, but I want only source files to be synced, not build, configuration, etc. I want to make it so that if a folder is named `src`, it and its contents get recursively synced.

For example, `~/workspace/src/file1.cpp` and `~/workspace/src/myfolder/file2.cpp` get synced but `~/workspace/build/file3.cpp` does not. I keep making and deleting projects and I do not want to have to re-configure file paths for syncing every time I create a new project with a new `src` directory.

Right now I'm using Unison file syncing tool for Mac and I don't know how to do this. Can someone show me?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it appears that Unison (alone) cannot easily do this. From the usage of `ignorenot xxx` in the [Unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs):

> In particular, putting `ignore = Path *` in your profile and then using `ignorenot` to select particular paths to be synchronized will not work. Instead, you should use the path preference to choose particular paths to synchronize.

Since that was exactly what I had in mind as a solution, means that there is no good solution. Here a few useful ideas though:

1. **Manually add a new path for each project**: This is just what the above quote suggests. For each new project you start and each new `src` directory you want to sync, add a line

   ```
   Path = path/to/src
   ```

   to your Unison profile.
2. **Manually ignore the build and configuration files**: Maybe all your build and configuration files have just a few different patterns you can match against? You could tell Unison to [ignore those patterns in particular](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#ignore) by adding something to your Unison profile like

   ```
   ignore = Name *.o              #ignore object files
   ignore = Name build            #ignore paths that end with "build"
   ignore = Name {.*,*}.sw[ponx]  #ignore pesky vim swap files
   ignore = ...
   ```
3. **Write a script to help**: You could certainly write a script that searches for all the directories named `src` and calls Unison on them individually. But that seems kinda silly. You *could* write a script that helps with point (1) above though. Write a script that finds all the paths named `src` and for each such path, add the line

   ```
   Path = /path/to/src
   ```

   to some file `AllThePaths`, and then just have the line

   ```
   include AllThePaths
   ```

   in your Unison profile.